# I want to add hyperlink in Excel file using Open XML and when click on hyperlink open another tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have added a sample line of code that's what i am trying to get my result. Please help if anybody have idea how to achieve this, only need using openXml library.

```
 Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink()
                {
                    Reference = "A" + indexer,
                    Location = "Unique" + (indexer - 1) + "!A1",
                    Display = "Unique" + indexer,
                };
                attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "inlineStr"));
                var cell = new Cell() { CellReference = hyperlink.Display };
                //cell.InnerText =  "dfd";
                writer.WriteStartElement(cell, attributes);
                //writer.WriteStartElement(hyperlink, attributes);
                //writer.WriteString("fdf");
                //writer.WriteElement(new InlineString(new Text("dfdfs")));
                writer.WriteStartElement(new InlineString(hyperlink));
                writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code to add hyperlink in Excel file using Open XML and when click on hyperlink open another tab:

```
                    if (attributes == null)
                    {
                        attributes = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    }
                     //Here I created the hyperlink
                    string xx = @"HYPERLINK(""[KillFile2.xlsx]Sheet1!A10"", ""Go to 
                    Sheet1 > A10"")";
                    attributes.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "inlineStr"));
                    writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), attributes);
                    //Here hyperlink added to cell formula
                    writer.WriteElement(new CellFormula(xx));
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
```